# Customize your FrameTicks in a MATLAB way

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

The figure below is made by MATLAB. However, the scientific form of numbers in `FrameTicks` that how MATLAB deals with is quite different from that of *Mathematica.*

[image: MATLAB plots with nice ticks]

By default, I plot the second figure based on the same data in a *Mathematica* way.
[image: Mathematica plots]
However, what is messy in the second figure is the overused ZERO in the vertical axis. So my first question is how to transform the number on the `FrameTicks` into some suitable scientific form.
Well, after we transform them into scientific form, my second question arises: how to make the plot in the MATLAB way? For example, if one of the frame ticks is 2*10^-4, I hope to put only 2 on the vertical axis and 10^-4 on the left top of the figure (Like the first one in the second column in the first figure).
I think we can test the idea based on

```
Plot[10^5 * Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

I think I can solve this problem in a stupid way: multiply/divide every number on the frame ticks by some number *x*, then place a graphics object of text which writes *x* to the left top side of the figure. But really what I need is a general way to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are many related questions around, search for [ticks + number](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ticks+number). You should also provide your *Mathematica* code used to generate your graphics - seems like some scaling issue is involved.

Comment: Thanks. However, I have tried searching for solution, still no better way to be implememt. Well, I should paste my code. But how about testing our ideas on the simple example I mentioned before the last paragraph. Thanks friend.

Comment: Please do post your code (as minimal working example), because things like `Grid` etc. may be playing a part as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can probably get close to what you want with some fiddling. Make the ticks to your satisfaction:

```
leftticks = Table[{k,NumberForm[k,ExponentFunction->(If[-2<#<2,Null,#]&)]},
   {k, -10^5, 10^5,50000.}]
rightticks = Table[{k,k/10^5},{k, -10^5, 10^5, 10.0^5/2}]
```

Then put them into the `Plot` function.

```
Labeled[
   Plot[10^5 Sin[x],{x,0,10},
     Frame -> True,
     FrameTicks->{{leftticks, rightticks}, {Automatic,None}}],
  {"*10^5", "1.2"}, {{Top,Right}}]
```

[image]

Perhaps the flexibility compensates for the fiddliness...

Answer (score 7):

You should post your source code for doing the fancy plots.. Yet, working from your suggested example, `TickLabelFunction` is an option from the `LevelScheme` package that does the trick. Get the package [here](http://scidraw.nd.edu/levelscheme/).

Run it:

```
<< LevelScheme`
```

And then use the `TickLabelFunction` to label your plot. Notice how you are not labeling the axes, but the frame. You go from this:

```
Plot[10^5*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[-1*^5, 1*^5, 5*^4, 4, 
     MajorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
     MinorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005]], 
    None}, {LinTicks[0, 10, 2, 4, MajorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
     MinorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005]], None}}]
```

[image]

To this

```
Plot[10^5*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[-1*^5, 1*^5, 5*^4, 4, 
     MajorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
     MinorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
     TickLabelFunction -> Function[x, N[x 1*^-5]]], 
    None}, {LinTicks[0, 10, 2, 4, MajorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
     MinorTickStyle -> Thickness[0.005]], None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a title, the accepted answer won't work very well. In this case, I think that the `Epilog`, `PlotRangeClipping->False`, `ImagePadding->40` might be the lowest effort solution, as seen here: [Epilog with text not shown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61764/epilog-with-text-not-shown).

Caveat: Won't work well if you have data that is outside of the range of your plot.

```
ListPlot[{{1, 0}, {3, 10}}
 , Epilog -> {Text["x10^-4", {1.0, 11.5}]}
 , PlotRangeClipping -> False
 , PlotLabel -> "Labeled Plot"]
```

[image]

It gets a bit more finnicky if you want to put the label on the upper right corner:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 0}, {3, 10}}
 , Epilog -> {Text["x10^-4", {3.0, 11.5}]}
 , PlotRangeClipping -> False
 , ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
 , PlotLabel -> "Labeled Plot"]
```

[image]