# Epilog with text not shown

Tags: plotting, graphics

I use the `Epilog` option in order to print in the vertical axes a label between 0 and 20 as follows

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, Epilog -> {Text[
Style["S", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold, 20], {-12, 
 10}]}]
```

[image]

However, the label is not shown in the plot. I also used `ImagePadding` to create more white space at the left right of the plot but without result. Any suggestions how to print this label? I don't want to use custom ticks.

Comment: You are telling it to put the text at {-12,10} but you are saying the plot range should be {-10,10} ? So it will not show up. Try `Plot[x^2, {x, -13, 10}, Frame -> True, Epilog -> {Text[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold, 20], {-12, 10}]}]`

Comment: Guys, wadr,  imho, this question is **not a simple mistake** nor  **can easily be found in the documentation**. It is a clearly stated question - one of the better ones in that -- and, there is no obvious solution i know of in the documentation or on this site. In fact, I have struggled with the same problem off and on until I bumped into ImagePadding/PlotRangeClipping combination -- and that only in the last two hours and thanks to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ImagePadding` with a large enough value and set the option `PlotRangeClipping` to `False`:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold, 20], {-12,10}]},
 ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using Overlay function with proper coodrinates.

maybe like this：

```
Overlay[{Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True], 
Style["S", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold, 20]}, 
Alignment -> Bottom]
```

[image]

I don't know is there any method to control the relative location of objects overlayed?

Comment: Could you provide a *Mathematica* code example. Otherwise this is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an infinite arrangement of labels exists and I doubt any degree of programming can offer all that a user can imagine. If one does not like the straightforward result of `FrameLabel`, as in `Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {None, Style["S", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold, 20], None, None}]`  (which has the label reading upward and in the middle of the frame), then I would switch to placing graphics primitives inside a `Graphics` command, such as `line = Line@Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -10, 10, .05}]; axes = {Line[{{-10, 0}, {10, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 100}}]}; Graphics[{line, Thickness[.007], axes, Text[Style["S", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, Bold, 20], {-12, 10}]}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]`. This lets you get exactly what you want at the cost of additional `Table` loops for curves, ticks, and such.