# How to combine scaled, rotated, etc. graphics objects?

Tags: graphics

This may be a trivial question, but I seem to be missing something.
Let's say I create a graphics object like so:

```
tp = Plot[{Sin[x], -Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
          Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> {Black, Black}, Filling -> Axis]
```

Now perhaps I want a rotated and scaled version of the same:

```
tprs = Magnify[Rotate[tp, 45*Degree], 0.5]
```

And now I want to have a graphic containing both of these:

```
Show[tp, tprs]
```

That last one fails, since tprs is not a graphics, according to Mathematica. What is it I am missing?

More generally I would like to be able to move around, rotate, and scale objects like my tp above arbitrarily, and combine them with other graphics objects within a single graphic. I guess what I really want is a new graphics primitive that I can later call as "objectname[{x,y}, s, \theta]" to make it appear at point {x, y} (relative to some reference point of the object), magnified by a factor s, and rotated by an angle \theta.

Comment: `Overlay[{tp, tprs}]` works, but I hate to use such a method...

Comment: Not a duplicate, because of the `Magnify`, but relevant:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57803/9490

Comment: Yep, I know about Overlay, but like you say, that's not really the right approach. I have seen the other thread you linked to, but in the end this doesn't quite do what I ultimately want, either. I think the real question is the one of how I can define a function as described in the last remark in my original post. A method to do something of that sort would be enormously helpful for many, many applications. It would allow us to create arbitrary graphical objects that act somewhat like the objects in libraries for bolts and nuts and valves and fittings, etc., etc. that CAD packages have.

Comment: You also need to use `Scale` instead of `Magnify` with the solution in the duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something quick and dirty like this,

```
rotateAndRescaleGraphics[g_Graphics, scale_, angle_] := 
  Module[{xr, yr},
   {xr, yr} = Charting`get2DPlotRange@g;
   g /. {x_?NumericQ, 
      y_?NumericQ} :> ({Rescale[#1, xr, scale xr], 
         Rescale[#2, yr, scale yr]} & @@ (RotationMatrix[angle].{x, 
          y}))
   ];

Show[tp,
 rotateAndRescaleGraphics[tp, 0.5, 45 Degree]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another, probably more powerful, way to go is to use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

```
Show[tp,
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[tp, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{.5, .5}], 
   RotationMatrix[45 Degree].{1, 0}]
 ]
```

which gives the exact same result as above.

Comment: This is awesome, since `Inset` does everything I want to do: I can scale, rotate, and shift. The only fly in the ointment is that, with stuff stuck in an `Epilog`, apparently `Show` doesn't know the size of graphics that are being added, so something like `PlotRange->All` does nothing. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Everything I'm reading says you need to manually add an `ImagePadding` specification, and then use `PlotRangeClipping -> False`.  See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61764/9490)

Comment: Hah, figured it out: The Epilog isn't needed, as long as we wrap `Graphics` around the `Inset`, like so: `Show[tp,
Graphics[Inset[tp, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, Scaled[{.5, .5}], 
   RotationMatrix[45 Degree].{1, 0}]]]`

Comment: Yeah, but there your `Inset` is already in the plot range.  Look at `Show[tp, Graphics[
  Inset[tp, {0, 0}, Center, Scaled[{.5, .5}], 
   RotationMatrix[45 Degree].{1, 0}]], PlotRange -> All]` - can't figure out how to show that without `ImagePadding`

Comment: Yes, this only allows me to get rid of the `Epilog` (I hate asymmetries that don't belong ;-), it doesn't solve the minor issue with PlotRange.

Comment: Oddly, if you use the `Inset` as the first argument to `Show`, it works:  `Show[Graphics[
  Inset[tp, {0, 0}, Center, Scaled[{.5, .5}], 
   RotationMatrix[45 Degree].{1, 0}]], tp, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Yeah, I just started playing around with this, and `Show` does strange things depending on the order in which its arguments appear. If I create several shifted and rotated copies of a graphics object, the window that `Show` produces changes in ways that are hard to understand. I really think it shouldn't be doing this, and I'm starting to lean towards considering this a bug. In my opinion, the output of `Show` should not depend on the order in which its arguments appear.

Answer (score 6):

As your own title says, you should use Scale instead of `Magnify` as follows:

```
tp = Plot[{Sin[x], -Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 1 Pi}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> {Black, Black}, Filling -> Axis];

tprs = Graphics[Scale[Rotate[tp[[1]], 45*Degree], 0.5]];

Show[tp, tprs]
```

[image]

To be able to apply `Scale`, I first extract the `Graphics` primitives returned by `Plot`. Afterwards, I wrap the result back into a `Graphics`.

Comment: Ahah! So the trick is to first do tp[[1]], and later wrap everything back in Graphics. It should be easy to turn this into a function that scales and rotates whatever graphics I want treated in this way. Now the only element that's missing is to move my graphics around... ;-)

Comment: @Pirx - Just add `Translate` at the appropriate point in the chain:  `....Translate[tp[[1]], {-1, 1}].....`

Comment: @JasonB Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Thanks @JasonB for the moving comment... Anyway, the nice thing is that these commands also work in 3D.

Comment: @Pirx. To get the placement you want for the transformed graphics, just use `tprs = Graphics[Rotate[Scale[tp[[1]], 0.5, {0, 0}], 45*Degree, {0, 0}]]`

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method using pure graphics.

```
form = 
  Module[{top, btm},
    top = N @ Table[{t, Sin[t]}, {t, Subdivide[π, 20]}];
    btm = Reverse[{1, -1} # & /@ top];
    {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[LightGray], FilledCurve[Line[top~Join~btm]]}];

Graphics[{Opacity[.7], form, Rotate[Scale[form, 0.5, {0, 0}], 45*Degree, {0, 0}]}]
```

[image: figure]